# Get user permission to write/delete on specific file from code

Tags: c#

I need sample code to get user permission and use this permission to access and modify specific files in the same application.

Some user have high security so the application have to be aware of this and ask them for access like prompt user account control.

[image]

there are sample code , its check file access rights but don't ask for permission ,[This post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14402/Testing-File-Access-Rights-in-NET)

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN's security center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570420) has much information on securing applications.

Also more info at the Windows Desktop dev center [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7/2818776#2818776
This is the answer thanks .